# making Windows 7 IIS FTP server unavailable for fault tolerance testing

Tags: windows-7, ftp, iis

I am working on testing java code (Apache commons net FTPClient) for fault tolerance to Windows 7 IIS FTP server. 
I need something that making Windows 7 IIS FTP server unavailable at random time by various reason.

So far for fault tolerance testing I created windows batch file that restarting  Windows 7 IIS FTP server after random period of time.

```
@echo off
:loop
SET /A rn=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
echo %rn%
ping -n %rn% 127.0.0.1
iisreset
goto loop
```

I feel like it's not really a good test that is covering only the FTP server restart and not covering other various reason when FTP may be unavailable.

Is there a better option for making Windows 7 IIS FTP server unavailable randomly by various reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a Batch file that stops the FTP service  (net stop "") and a batch file that starts the service (net start""). Call them randomly using task scheduler. See screenshot
[image]